# Can not access local network domains when Cisco AnyConnect is connected

Tags: cisco-vpn-client, cisco-anyconnect

On Windows 10 machine I have Cisco AnyConnect that is connected to a client VPN in order to access their network. However when Cisco AnyConnect is active/connected I can no longer access machines/applications by their domains in my office network. Accessing with IP works fine.

How to access my local office network machines/applications by domain name when Cisco AnyConnect is active/connected?

Comment: I am assuming you are connecting to VPN connection profile with DNS traffic to go inside the tunnel. Do you have option to choose a different connection profile where DNS traffic is not tunneled ?

Comment: `I am assuming you are connecting to VPN connection profile with DNS traffic to go inside the tunnel` Is there a way I can check this assumption by myself? Of course I can ask admins of the client about that.

`Do you have option to choose a different connection profile where DNS traffic is not tunneled ?` that is probably something that I should ask admins of the client as well.

Comment: If you have Cisco DART tool, please collect logs and share the ftp link. I can take a look. Unfortunately, AnyConnect UI doesn't advertise about DNS traffic being tunneled in its Statistics page.